# Как в owl-carousel сделать счетчик слайдеров и добавить класс для item?

Tags: javascript, owl-carousel

Счетчик начинает считать слайдеры с 0 , как можно сделать подсчет с 1 слайдера ?

```
$(function(){
    var owl = $('.Contentslider .owl-carousel');

    owl.owlCarousel({
      loop:true,
      autoplay: false,
      items:1, 
      nav: true,
      dots: true,
      navText: ['◄','►'], 
      startPosition: 1,  
      onInitialized  : counter, //When the plugin has initialized.
      onTranslated : counter //When the translation of the stage has finished.
    });

    function counter(event) {
       var element   = event.target;         // DOM element, in this example .owl-carousel
        var items     = event.item.count;     // Number of items
        var item      = event.page.index + 1;     // Position of the current item
      $('.counter').html(""+item+" / "+items)
    } 
    });
```

и возможно для item добавить класс ?

```
 $('.counter').html(""+item+" / "+items)
```

Сейчас выводится счетчик вот так - 0 / 2 , надо 2 / 2

Answer (score 0):

```js
function counter(event) {
  console.log(event)
  var element = event.target; // DOM element, in this example .owl-carousel
  var items = event.item.count; // Number of items
  var item = (event.page.index === -1 ? 1 : event.page.index) + 1; // Position of the current item
  $('.counter').html("<span class='test'>" + item + "</span> / " + items)
}
```